# Windows Authentication Error 401.2

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-config, windows-authentication

I have created a new empty project `Asp.Net Web Application` but I dont want to use `MVC or WebForms`, I wanted to use `Windows Authentication`.

I have already added in `web.config` file the following code:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

After adding that code when i run the project it says: `Access Negated ... etc ... Error 401.2 You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials you supplied.`

On the other hand, without that code the `Application` runs properly, but it **doesn't authenticate the user**...

So my question is: **How to add Windows Authentication in empty project?**

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
For some reason i cant choose nothing, the option is disabled.

[See the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vwb7S.png)

Comment: You also have to enable Windows authentication at the server/site level.  If you are using IIS Express, you should be able to configure that in Visual Studio - click on the project in Solution Explorer and in the properties window there should be a Windows Authentication option that needs to be set to enabled.  See if that is set right.

Comment: check out my edit. @Mark

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. Not the project properties, but the properties window (press F4 maybe, can't remember). I'll post a screenshot when I get to work.

Comment: Ah yes i just found where it was thank you ;) @Mark